# Naming of tuples in string format

Tags: python

I have a list of tuples like this `[('Note', 1), ('Task', 1), ('Note', 2)]`, which get turned into strings for easy saving to a Postgres db.

This means that when retrieved they look like `["('Note', 1)", "('Task', 1)", "('Note', 2)"]` and I am unsure how to describe this version of them.

For now I'm calling them "string-based tuples" because I am using literal_eval to turn them back into real tuples (like the first version), but am wondering if there is a more standard way to describe them.

Comment: They might be called the string representation of the tuples, after all `('Note',1).__repr__() == "('Note', 1)"`.

Comment: I'm inclined to call `"('Note', 1)"` a tuple's repr. I don't like "string-based tuples" because they aren't tuples anymore, but I guess I'd accept "stringified tuple" or "stringized tuple" or even "[serialized](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serialization) tuple", although that's a bit broad.

Comment: Thanks @AndrasDeak, that makes sense